# Populating a chart control and a datagrid using the same datareader

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, datareader

I have a chart control and datagrid in the same page.

I want in a single button click, to populate them both using a datareader.

I have this code:

```
dg.datasource=reader
dg.databind()

Chart1.Series("series1").Points.DataBind(
    reader, 
    "product_name", 
    "SumOfpriceafterall", 
    "Tooltip=SumOfpriceafterall, Label=quantity{C2}")
```

The problem is that only one of them is populated (the first databind in the code) and the other databind isn't working.

Why does this happen and what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Because datareader is forward only datasource. Once the grid is populated, the cursor reaches the end and the datareader is finished.
So during the second bind (chart.bind), the datareader contains no data.
Use dataset instead that can go forwards and backwards or else you have to reobtain the same datareader after the first databind.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083365/11808), if you want to avoid using dataset or reobtaining the same datareader, you can do the following trick.

In the code behind, use the gridview.rowdatabound event and for each datarow added to the gridview, use the same data to plot X,Y on the chart. Something like:

```
Protected Sub myGV_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles myGV.RowDataBound

    Dim Field1 as string, Field2 as string

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Field1 = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Field1")  ' X Value
        Field2 = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Field2")  ' Y value
        ' Plot on the chart the above X,Y
    End If
End Sub
```